# Stability of equilibrium in four-dimensional space

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know that in two-dimensional and three-dimensional spaces if all eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix are negative then the equilibrium is stable. And if at least one eigenvalue is positive and at least one eigenvalue is negative then it forms a saddle (unstable).

I am now working in a four-dimensional space. I have three eigenvalues that are negative and one that is positive. Am I correct in thinking that my equilibrium forms a saddle? Or are there different formations in a four-dimensional space?